# DTEXEC started but no response

Tags: ssis

I have a strange problem when running DTEXEC to run a SSIS package.

my command is dtexec /Project /Package.

I get no error but get a screen that simply says

"Started DD-MM-YY", no error, just nothing.

Has anyone ever seen this before, read the MSDN documentation to no avail.

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer, I was specifying the whole "path" in the package name for the package. I needed to do /package "Package.dtsx" instead of "C:/Blah/Package.dtsx"

Hope it helps someone else

Comment: The missing piece :) thank you sir! Was executing from SQL server using xp_cmdshell and it was always returning NULL. With this, runs all the way through.